# Can't insert images into LibreOffice 7.3.2.2 Writer document in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice

I just upgraded two dual boot (Windows/Ubuntu) laptops from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04. So far everything works OK except for the following situation.

In the first dual boot laptop I cannot insert an image into a LibreOffice (version 7.3.2.2) Writer document nor see images inserted into a Writer document which were created before this upgrade. In this laptop both OSs (Windows and Ubuntu) are installed on the same HDD.

In the second laptop Windows and Ubuntu are installed on separate HDDs. Inserting an image into a LibreOffice Writer document works OK, and images in LibreOffice Writer documents which were created before this upgrade can be seen normally.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is yet another issue related to Wayland. Log out, before entering your password click the cog wheel in the bottom right of the login  screen and select "Ubuntu on Xorg" there. Report back if that the issue then still is produced.

Comment: @vanadium Thank you for your advice ! I made as you advised and selected 'Ubuntu on Xorg'. But unfortunately the situation remains unchanged, i.e. in the LO 7.3.2.2 Writer document is only empty frame for the inserted (copy/paste) picture, but the picture itself can not be seen. Also pictures inserted into this same document before this Ubuntu upgrade cannot be seen; there also only an empty frame of the earlier inserted picture is seen.

Comment: You will then better add some hardware info to your post (use "edit"), especially about the graphics card.

Comment: @vanadium Thank you for reply. The GPU of the laptop with this LO problem is AMD Caicos. But before this upgrade 20.04 -> 22.04 this problem did not took place. The GPU of the other laptop without this LO problem - also after this upgrade -  is AMD Turks.

Comment: Edit your question, add the details there. Not everybody reads through all the comments. These are just there to improve questions and answers.

Comment: I found solution to this issue: Open LibreOffice Writer -> Tools -> Settings -> LibreOffice Writer -> View -> Show -> tick into Pictures and images.

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice 7.3.2.2 Writer has some new features that are not included in the LibreOffice Writer 6.4.7.2 version which is currently installed by default in Ubuntu 20.04.

In LibreOffice Writer 7.3.2.2 select *Tools* -> *Options* -> *LibreOffice Writer* -> *View* -> Under the **Display** section check the checkbox to the left of *Images and objects* (marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot) -> Click the *Apply* button -> Click the *OK* button.

[image]